# Getting the array length from an array in the vue data object

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am having a bit of a problem getting an array length in vue. The array
is in the data object as

```
data() {
    return {
      slides: [
        {
          image: require("@/assets/img/carousel/couple.jpg"),
          caption:
            "A couple wearing masks kiss in a shopping area in downtown Shanghai, China, on February 16, 2020."
        },
        {
          image: require("@/assets/img/carousel/dogs.jpg"),
          caption:
            "Dogs wearing masks are seen in a shopping area in downtown Shanghai on February 16, 2020."
        },
         etc... ]
```

and then in methods

```
methods: {
    playSlides() {
      this.imgSource = this.slides[this.currentSlide].image;
      this.figCaption = this.slides[this.currentSlide].caption;
      let slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);

      function nextSlide() {
        console.log(`slides.length is: ${this.slides.length}`);
        this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.slides.length; // % is same as mod operator
        console.log(Array.isArray(this.slides));
      }
    }
  }
};
```

I know its been a long day but this.slides.length is undefined?? and Array.isArray(this.slides) is false. Any body see what is the problem most appreciated...

Comment: `const nextSlide = () => {...}` to bind `this`.

Comment: Sorry. still getting undefined.

Comment: You probably got undefined because you declared the variable nextSlide below where you used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `function name()`, the this context is not the this context of the parent object, it is in fact the this context of window.

In order to make `this` equal to the vue instance, you have to use an arrow function, or use the [.bind prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly bind what you want `this` to be in your function.

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      currentSlide: 1,
      slides: [{
          image: "@/assets/img/carousel/couple.jpg",
          caption: "A couple wearing masks kiss in a shopping area in downtown Shanghai, China, on February 16, 2020."
        },
        {
          image: "@/assets/img/carousel/dogs.jpg",
          caption: "Dogs wearing masks are seen in a shopping area in downtown Shanghai on February 16, 2020."
        }
      ]
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.playSlides();
    this.playSlides2();
  },

  methods: {
    playSlides() {
      this.imgSource = this.slides[this.currentSlide].image;
      this.figCaption = this.slides[this.currentSlide].caption;
      let slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide.bind(this), 2000);

      function nextSlide() {
        console.log(`slides.length is: ${this.slides.length}`);
        this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.slides.length; // % is same as mod operator
        console.log(Array.isArray(this.slides));
      }
    },

    playSlides2() {
      this.imgSource = this.slides[this.currentSlide].image;
      this.figCaption = this.slides[this.currentSlide].caption;

      const nextSlide = () => {
        console.log(`slides.length is: ${this.slides.length}`);
        this.currentSlide = (this.currentSlide + 1) % this.slides.length; // % is same as mod operator
        console.log(Array.isArray(this.slides));
      }

      let slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide, 2000);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Mucho appreciado. I changed this line to let slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide.bind(this), 2000); and now all is working. Everyone stay safe.

Comment: Oh yes! my bad. Edited the answer. I was running the function directly to debug, and I forgot that setinterval is taking a function as callback. Good spot!